# Meaning of "take title in"?

Tags: meaning

> Tomorrow around 3:30, I need a ride from the 7-11 to the quick cash place, gonna take my title in for some funds.

I take it *title* here means the legal right to own something? And *to take your title in for some funds* means to get some funds in your title?

Comment: What are you quoting? It sounds like a character in a story or article, or perhaps it is something that you overheard. If might help to know where this quotation is coming from (continent, country, city, etc.), to look up what this phrase means.

Comment: It's a comment from some poster she was asked if she needed a ride, but I think Rory's answer is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context it seems to imply an ownership document - perhaps for a property or car - to either use as security on a loan until pay day, or to prove his place of residence so the loan shark knows where do find him if he doesn't pay up.

Answer (score 0):

**Title** here refers to this meaning of the word:

> A right or claim to the ownership of property.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/title

And one of the examples clarifies the usage: **The company has the legal and beneficial title to its property.**